# SQL Server bulk openrowset access is denied for windows user but not for sa

Tags: sql-server, bulk, openrowset

When I am logged in as the **sa** user I am able to run the following command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '\\server1\files\test.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) x
```

However, when I log in as my **windows user** who has sysadmin, bulkadmin and serveradmin roles I get the following error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot bulk load because the file "\server1\files\test.pdf" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

What permissions am I missing from my Windows user?

Comment: It's probably what permissions are you missing from the filesystem folder and/or share.

Comment: I don't think this is a folder permissions issue as the sa user is able to successfully run the command.

Comment: Is this the actual error message?  The path "\server1\files\test.pdf" should start with "\\", otherwise it's a local path.

Comment: Yes, that is the actual message. I moved the file locally and got the same error message (different path ofcourse). The path is '\\server1", not "\server1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent this problem by creating a SQL job that called my stored procedure where the bulk insert script occurs. When the job is run, the SQL agent credentials are used and the blob is read.

Answer (score 0):

`sa` will run `OPENROWSET(BULK` as the SQL Server Service Account, which will map to the Machine Account for built-in users like `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` or `Network Service`.  Windows Logins will run `OPENROWSET(BULK` as themselves.

Comment: It's really interesting you say that. I ran the same command on another SQL instance using my windows user successfully.

Comment: Is there any logging I can review that will provide more visibility into the error?

Comment: I realize I was running this command in SSMS on an application server in the same network (using the same user I have been using all along). I logged on to the SQL server itself and reran the command via SSMS on the local server with success (logged in as the same user).

Would this point to a double hop issue with authentication?